# duplicate symbols for architecture arm64(xcode 8)

Tags: ios, xcode

It show this after I use `cocopod` to install the tools
and it does not work even I deleted the `libPods-MagicSquare-SDWebImage.a`

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you check is anywhere you are importing .m file.

Comment: project can run before I used cocopod so I think code is right

Comment: you used sdwebimage in podfile also?

Answer (score 0):

This link error means the symbol `SDWebImagePrefetcher` occurred in both SDWebImage and MagicSquare-SDWebImage library. You could try to search the code in global files in workspace and find it.

To resolve it, you could remove the one of the library references. I guess the latter one MagicSquare-SDWebImage should be implemented base on SDWebImage library, so you should try to remove the SDWebImage library reference. You may need to update the cocoapods config by running `pod update` and clean & build the project.